# Indexing images read with with repa-devil

Tags: haskell, repa

I'm trying to examine the RGB components of pixels in an image, but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
import Data.Array.Repa
import Data.Array.Repa.IO.DevIL
import Data.Word (Word8)

main = do
  (RGB ps) <- runIL $ readImage "test.jpeg"
  let k = (Z :. 142) :. 212 :. 0 :: DIM3
  print $ ps ! k
```

The error I get is:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( amy.hs, interpreted )

amy.hs:8:15:
    Couldn't match expected type `Array r0 DIM3 a0'
                with actual type `repa-3.2.3.1:Data.Array.Repa.Base.Array
                                    repa-3.2.3.1:Data.Array.Repa.Repr.ForeignPtr.F
                                    repa-3.2.3.1:Data.Array.Repa.Index.DIM3
                                    Word8'
    In the first argument of `(!)', namely `ps'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `ps ! k'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: print $ ps ! k
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

For starters, I don't understand the message. It looked like the compiler expected an `Array something DIM3 something`, and it got an `Array F DIM3 Word8`. Why don't these types match up? I've read the [Repa Tutorial](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell%3a_A_Repa_Tutorial#Indexing_arrays) on the Haskell wiki, but I still don't see how to make this work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may have two different versions of `repa` in play. Check by saying

```
ghc-pkg list repa
```

and see how many versions show up. I suspect you're importing `Data.Array.Repa` from one instance, but `Data.Array.Repa.IO.DevIL` depends on the other. The hint is in the error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Array r0 DIM3 a0'
            with actual type `repa-3.2.3.1:Data.Array.Repa.Base.Array
```

Once, GHC says `Array`, and once, it says `repa-3.2.3.1:Data.Array.Repa.Base.Array`. This usually means that it explicitly wants to make a difference between two occurrences of the type `Array` here.

If my suspicion is correct, you can either hide one version of `repa` (the one that's **not** version `3.2.3.1` and being used by `repa-devil`) by passing

```
-hide-package repa-<version>
```

(with the correct version number filled in) to GHC, or you can hide the package via

```
ghc-pkg hide repa-<version>
```

Comment: D'oh! That was the problem, indeed. I should have suspected that. And now I understand the error message.